Error: spawn EINVAL when trying to create a Quip Live App
I am very new to QUIP and when trying to build the "hello world" live app here:
https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/1.x.x/guide/get-started/build-a-hello-world-app
I am getting a Error: spawn EINVAL error and a waring about a few depricated packages:
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\xxx> npm install -g quip-cli
npm warn deprecated @oclif/command@1.8.36: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm warn deprecated @oclif/help@1.0.15: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm warn deprecated @oclif/errors@1.3.6: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm warn deprecated @oclif/errors@1.3.5: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm warn deprecated @oclif/config@1.18.2: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm warn deprecated @oclif/config@1.18.17: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm warn deprecated @oclif/config@1.18.16: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.
npm warn deprecated @oclif/parser@3.8.17: Package no longer supported. Contact Support at https://www.npmjs.com/support for more info.

changed 111 packages in 12s

16 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
PS C:\Users\xxx> quip-cli login
You're already logged in to quip.com. Pass --force to log in again or --site to log in to a different site.
PS C:\Users\xxx> quip-cli init
Creating a new Quip Live App
? What is the name of this app?
(This is what users will see when inserting your app)
 Quip Test
? Choose a toolbar color red
? Choose a package name quip-test
? What does this app do?
 A Quip Live App
? Use Typescript? Yes
? Would you like to customize your manifest.json now?
(see: https://corp.quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#app-manifest)
 Yes
? Disable commenting at the app level? No
? Choose a sizing mode
(see: https://corp.quip.com/dev/liveapps/recipes#specifying-the-size-of-your-app) fill_container
? Specify an initial height for your app
This will be the height of the app while it is loading.
 300
? Specify an initial width for your app (optional)
This will be the width of the app while it is loading.
 -1
Creating app in dev console...
App created: EOLAjA8D0bk, v0.0.0 (0)
installing dependencies...
Command failed: npm.cmd install
CWD: C:\Users\xxx\quip-test
Error: spawn EINVAL
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
    at C:\Users\newmak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quip-cli\lib\lib\util.js:28:37
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at exports.runCmdPromise (C:\Users\newmak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quip-cli\lib\lib\util.js:27:12)
    at exports.runCmd (C:\Users\newmak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quip-cli\lib\lib\util.js:13:20)
    at Init.run (C:\Users\newmak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quip-cli\lib\commands\init.js:222:26)
    at async Init._run (C:\Users\newmak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quip-cli\node_modules\@oclif\command\lib\command.js:43:20)
    at async Config.runCommand (C:\Users\newmak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quip-cli\node_modules\@oclif\config\lib\config.js:173:24)
    at async Main.run (C:\Users\newmak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quip-cli\node_modules\@oclif\command\lib\main.js:28:9)
PS C:\Users\newmak>

The directory/app does get created but there is no app.ele file in any of the folders? Is this due to the spawn EINVAL issue or am I missing a step?

